# C# LDAP Backup - Create an LDIF file

Tags: c#, ldap, backup

Does anyone know, or know of any examples of how to write a proram that backs up an ldap store to an ldif file? i need to write a program because we cannot install any other open source software like jxplorer on our machines. Any assistence will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using openldap, found this: http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin/dbtools.html

> The slapcat program is used to dump the database to an LDIF file. This
>   can be useful when you want to make a human-readable backup of your
>   database or when you want to edit your database off-line. The program
>   is invoked like this:

```
slapcat -l <filename> -f <slapdconfigfile> [-d <debuglevel>] [-n <databasenumber>|-b <suffix>]
```

> where -n or -b is used to select the database in the slapd.conf(5)
>   specified using -f. The corresponding LDIF output is written to
>   standard output or to the file specified using the -l option.